# nodejs md5 with raw_output like md5(data, raw_output) in php

Tags: php, node.js

`md5` in php:

> md5 ( string $str [, bool $raw_output = false ] )
>
> If the optional raw_output is set to TRUE, then the md5 digest is instead returned in raw binary format with a length of 16.

so you can do this following in php:

```
$ php -a
>>> md5('data', true)
=> b"ìw\x7F8]=■╚ü] ¸I`&▄"
```

I was tried using crypto in nodejs:

```
$ node
>>> crypto.createHash('md5').update('data').digest('binary')
'w8]=þÈ] ÷I`&Ü'
```

But the result not same

I want to encrypt data with raw_output option in nodejs, how to achieve it？

Comment: Googling "node md5 binary" brings up https://gist.github.com/theotow/8577001.

Comment: @ceejayoz,but the result is not same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had your encoding as 'binary' use 'hex' instead

```
crypto.createHash('md5').update('data').digest('hex')
```

https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_hash_digest_encoding

Comment: it return '8d777f385d3dfec8815d20f7496026dc', still not same

Comment: How is it not the same?

Comment: If it's the single vs. double quote, then that's just how the repl displays it. You can ignore it, the strings do match

Comment: I want to encrypt data with raw_output option in nodejs, the result shoule be binary `ìw\x7F8]=■╚ü] ¸I`&▄` instead of `8d777f385d3dfec8815d20f7496026dc`

Comment: It's binary. It doesn't matter how it displays in repl, it's the same bits. If you base64 encoded both binary outputs, they would match. In node digest, use `.digest()` to get a Buffer, or `.digest('base64')`

Answer (score 0):

All of these do the same:

```
Mac OS command line:  md5 -q -s "my string" | xxd -p -r | openssl base64

PHP: $hash = md5("my string", true); $result = base64_encode($hash);

Node.JS:  crypto.createHash('md5').update("my string", "binary").digest('base64');
```